# Jquery dialog and session attributes

Tags: jquery, request

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".add").click(function() {
            $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
    });
    $(".update").click(function() {
                //ID value will be replaced... 
        $.get("updateCategoryPage?category_id=ID", function (data) {
            $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
        });


    });
</script>
```

I have two buttons for adding and updating with class add and update respectively .
so wen some one clicks i am making a controller call in $.get method as shown above
It s making call and executing controller code and coming back to same page.

/* Here i have a form with some fields and values of those are the object values like 
Student name and student id... in controller i am setting the request scope with student object and coming to this page but values are not being displayed! in update popup dialog */

I want to reuse same code for adding and updating previously i had two jsps for adding and updating, my req now is to use the same jsp page i am stuck with this problem help me asap..

Comment: you have a problem in `"updateCategoryPage?category_id=ID"` here ID is a variable so you were to use string concatenation like `"updateCategoryPage?category_id="+ID`

Answer (score 1):

As Arun mentioned the problem in your code is you need to concat the ID variable like `"updateCategoryPage?category_id="+ID`
For you [this](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form) site can be helpful.It has got nice UI in case you want to change your UI too if you like.Also just a tip.If you want to post more than one variable you can do it like:`"updateCategoryPage?category_id="+ID+"/"+NAME`
All the best.